# How do I resolve a dependency in a Class Library from the container configured in Startup?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mocking

The objective is using IoC and being able to [mock dependencies] for unit testing.

The project: .NET Core Web API with multiple class libraries

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection for my IoC and I'd like to keep using it if it supports what I'm trying to accomplish.

The problem: At least one class in my assemblies (class libraries) has a dependency that needs to mocked (e.g. using Moq). I completely understand that I can use constructor injection to inject the interface but that doesn't fit the scenario.

What I'm simply trying to accomplish in my assembly is to resolve the dependency using the container that I initiated in my Startup class of the Web API.

How would I do that? And if that isn't possible, what may be another way to accomplish the same thing, i.e. mocking my printer without using dependency injection?

Below is some sample code which hopefully clarifies this a bit.

Web API's Startup.cs (has a reference to assembly which defines printer)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IPrinter, Printer>();
}
```

In a different assembly, I'd like to resolve an instance of Printer using the same container.

```
    public interface IPrinter
    {
        void Print(string text);
    }

    public class Printer : IPrinter
    {
        public void Print(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing: " + text);
        }
    }


    public class Task
    {
        public void PrintSomething(string text)
        {
            //do not 'new up' but resolve it from the container of Startup.cs
            var printer = new Printer(); 
            printer.Print(text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not constructor injection ? Why it does not fit ?

Comment: what is the construction hierarchy behind the Task class in your case?

Comment: @Shyju - I don't see using constructor injection (or property injection) for every class that I may mock or that I may 'new up'. Using that pattern alone for every class can get quite unmanageable in a larger solution.

Comment: Using DI will make your code unit testable.

Comment: This is a design issue masked behind an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

This is a design issue masked behind an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You have already shot down the [The Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

```
public class PrintTask {
    private readonly IPrinter printer;

    public PrintTask(IPrinter printer) {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void PrintSomething(string text) {
        printer.Print(text);
    }
}
```

Which would allow the dependent class, having already being registered with the container

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IPrinter, Printer>();
    services.AddScoped<PrintTask>();
}
```

from being a flexible decoupled class whose dependencies could be easily mocked and injected.

Dependency Injection is the best bet here but there is also the Service Locator anti-pattern, which, while workable, is not usually advised.